# How can I import a web pack compiled function without using weback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

i am aware that bundles compiled by webpack dont write to the global namespace.

But what is the best practice though, to import stuff that is compiled by webpack (e.g.: a vendor.js created by splitChunks) into a non webpack project? I have some old backend code that is creating a html file -line by line-. There i want to include and re-use some new UI components that are bundled.
Also, in the webpack config i have some legacy global functions (e.g.: "GlobalFunction") declared via the ProvidePlugin Plugin.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="everything" class="everything">
      <script src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="commons.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
      <script>
        GlobalFunction();

        ReactDOM.render(
          React.createElement(Component1, {
            prop1: '1',
            prop2: '2',
          }, null),
          document.getElementById('mainbody')
        );

      </script>
    </div>
    <div id='mainbody'>
      <!--- rendered by react -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the issue is, that **GlobalFunction** and **ReactDOM** are not known and therefore throwing "not defined" error. Of course, when i instead source ReactDOM from a CDN like

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

ReactDOM is properly in context, but Component1 (beeing defined in app.bundle.js) is then not known.

below is just for reference:

**app.js** (correctly exposed)

```
export class Component1 extends React.Component {
...
}
```

**webpack.conf** This is how the bundles were compiled (not sure about the libraryTarget option). Webpack is not used for this Project.

```
//...
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
              test: /node_modules/,
              chunks: "all",
              name: "vendor",
              priority: 10,
              enforce: true
            },
            commons: {
              chunks: "initial",
              minChunks: 2,
              maxInitialRequests: 5,
              minSize: 0
            }
          },
        },
      },
//...
      output: {
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '/dist'),
          filename: '[name].bundle.js',
          libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      },
//...
      plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jquery: "jquery",
          GlobalFunction: ['../global.js', 'doGlobalFunction'],
        })
      ]
```

thank you in advance!

### **UPDATE**

I tried the following two but still no success

**webpack.conf** (introducing library "testLib" so hopefully i would be able to access this from outside the webpack context and write the global function also into window.

```
//...
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'ui/ext/static/dist'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      libraryTarget: 'var',
      library:'testLib'
  },
//...
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jquery: "jquery",
        GlobalFunction: ['../global.js', 'doGlobalFunction'],
        "window.GlobalFunction" : ['../global.js', 'doGlobalFunction']
      })
  ]
```

unfortunately i was not able to access GlobalFunction and also no access to testLib

Comment: Are you sure that your bundles JS isn't obfuscated in some way? "Component1" is probably replaced by a minified var name. Is it that difficult to just use the core files together with RequireJS?

Comment: Well I haven’t checked for Component1, as it was just playing around with including react via CDN. 
My intention is to use react and other third party node modules out of vendors.bundle.js … 
I think there is a general misunderstanding from my side. This is a context/namespace issue, as I can’t even call ReactDOM out of the vendors.bundle.js
As for RequireJS, haven’t used or took it into consideration so far. How would that fit into what I want to do?

Comment: In your webpacked entry you can tack stuff on to the global (`window`) namespace so it's accessible outside of the webpacked code.

Comment: You could decompile the bundle into something more usable using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/debundle. You will need to manually modify the output but that will probably save time in the long run compared to some hacky solution that involves modifying the bundle.

Comment: @DaveNewton ... this sounds promising do you have an example? How do i need to change my bundle configuration so that vendors, global functions and all other are accessible?

Diasiare , thank you but i rather choose to change my bundle config instead of doing debundling which sounds also really hacky :/

Comment: We're using two mechanisms for this; one is a separate webpack config for the stuff that isn't part of our Reactified app, one that exposes stuff that is. In our app.js we just check for `window` and if it's there, just attaches stuff to `window`. The other uses jQuery's DOMready and does the same thing.

Comment: checked my update? :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a way to get things working finally. Its not nice as it pollutes the window object, but it suits my needs. This is anyway just a stop gap solution until old legacy code is replaced or ported.

I have created a new entry point in my webpack.conf,

e.g.: exposedStuff.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Component1} from 'component1.jsx'

// expose what is imported via 'import'
window["React"] = React;
window["ReactDOM"] = ReactDOM;
window["Component1"] = Component1;
// expose what is globally defined via ProvidePlugin
window["GlobalFunction"] = GlobalFunction;
```

include new file also to the .html part

```
...
<script src="exposedStuff.bundle.js"></script>
...
```